# How does "matching objects" work in Python's pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, python-3.10

The term "matching objects" is taken from [PEP 636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-a-ui-matching-objects).

At the first glance, Python seems to extract a path to the involved attributes from the construction-like expression in `case` and optionally do the assignment if there are variables for binding:

```
class M:
  def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
    self.c = a + b
    print(f"{self.c} = {a} + {b}")

match M(a=1, b=2):
  case M(a=1, b=2):
    print("branch ab")
  case M(c=3):
    print(f"branch c")
```

which prints

```
3 = 1 + 2
branch c
```

For me, the `M(a=1, b=2)` in the first `case` is not a construction (as there is only one `3 = 1 + 2` printout), but rather a representation of the path to attribute `c` of `M`. There is no attribute `a` or `b` in `M`, so the first `case` cannot be matched.

But for built-in classes, the matching seems to be w.r.t. values:

```
match 0:
  case 0+0j:
    print("matched?")
  case _:
    print("not matched")
```

Although the types are `int` and `complex` respectively, `0` matches `0+0j`.

---

Another question raises when capturing a method. Let's modify the first example as

```
class M:
  def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
    self.c = a + b
    self.f = lambda x, y: self.c + x + y

match M(a=1, b=2):
  case M(f=f):
    print(f(1, 2))
```

which prints `6` as expected. But this is not true for `int`:

```
match 0:
  case int(__add__=add):
    print(int.__add__, add)
    print(f"{add(1, 2)} = 1 + 2")
```

The printout will show `int.__add__` and `add` are functions with different nature:

```
<slot wrapper '__add__' of 'int' objects> <method-wrapper '__add__' of int object at 0x7f162fee40d0>
```

In fact, `add` can only take 1 argument not 2. An exception will be thrown from the above snippet:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line xx, in <module>
    print(f"{add(1, 2)} = 1 + 2")
TypeError: expected 1 argument, got 2
```

And if fed with one argument, `add` will simply return that argument. So what is this `method-wrapper` and why is the change in the behaviour?

Comment: Regarding `0` matching `0+0j`, this is (I think) related to the numeric tower defined in the `numbers` module. `0` is an instance of `Integral` which subclasses `Rational` which subclasses `Real` which subclasses `Complex`, so `0` and `0+0j` are, in fact, two different literals that produce equal values.

Comment: In the second example, `__add__` is the class attribute you matched against, while `add` is the bound method resulting from `(0).__add__`.

Comment: @chepner That makes sense. Thank you! You can write them into an answer so that I can accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

```
match 0:
  case 0+0j:
    print("matched?")
  case _:
    print("not matched")
```

The `numbers` module defines a hierarchy of numeric types; the relevant path here is that `0` is an instance of `Integral`, which is a subclass of `Rational`, which is a subclass of `Real`, which is a subclass of `Complex`. As a result, the value `0` is considered a match to the [literal pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#literal-patterns) `0+0j`, as `0 == 0 + 0j` is true.

Regarding

```
match 0:
  case int(__add__=add):
    print(int.__add__, add)
    print(f"{add(1, 2)} = 1 + 2")
```

The pattern `int(__add__=add)` is a [class pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#class-patterns) that contains a capture pattern for the `__int__` attribute of the matched value. In this case, `(0).__add__` is bound to the name `add`.